# Jquery scroll-to not scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have it so when the user clicks a link it scrolls down so that the blue area is off the top of the page.

This is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z66rD/2/)

I think the code would be something like this:

```
$("#scroll").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#jumbo").offset().bottom
    }, 2000);
});
```

However it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong please?

Comment: Doesn't `offset()` only return `top` and `left` for positioning purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`offset()` only exposes the `top` and `left` properties. To get the bottom you need to add the height to `top`:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".jumbo").offset().top + $(".jumbo").height()
}, 2000);
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z66rD/4/)

Also, note that in your example `jumbo` is a class, not an id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for scrolling to the first `.midheight` div:

```
$("#scroll").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".midheight:eq(0)").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z66rD/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jQuery for this, you can simply use anchors.

Anchors are links but with hashes, for example:

```
<a name="scroll_down"></a>
```

These can then be targeted with a normal link, but set out like this:

```
<a href="#scroll_down"></a>
```

Clicking the link will scroll you down the page to where the anchor is put in your HTML.

For the slow animation that you're after, you can look [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) and use his code. All credit to him for the code, works great.

Here is your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dam7G/)

The good thing about this, is you can easily use to it have links to each of the "features" you had in the fiddle and have an anchor above each so the user can scroll down to the appropriate are easily, and without the need for you to have repeating jQuery code.